# qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

Tags: windows-10, python3, anaconda, qt, pyqt

I had anaconda running on my machine. few days ago i had to update some of the libraries because they were outdated.
after the update, I was not able to launch anaconda-navigator or spyder anymore due to the following error:

```
(base) C:\>qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I've tried the following:

*unistall/reinstall the whole package
*following commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda install pyqt5
pip install pyqt5
```

*reset spyder settings

the installed packages and urls:

```
(base) C:\>SPYDER
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 202, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 48, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 208, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

(base) C:\>conda list --show-channel-urls
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0    defaults
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0    conda-forge
anaconda                  custom                   py37_0    defaults
anaconda-client           1.7.2                      py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0    defaults
anaconda-project          0.8.2                      py_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py37_1003    conda-forge
astroid                   2.2.5                    py37_0    conda-forge
astropy                   3.1.2            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
atomicwrites              1.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.6.0                      py_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.os              0.1.1                 py37_1000    conda-forge
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                      py_3    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.7.1                 py37_1001    conda-forge
bitarray                  0.9.2            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0    defaults
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
blosc                     1.16.3               h6538335_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                     py_0    conda-forge
boto3                     1.9.143                    py_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.12.143                   py_1    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.2.1           py37h452e1ab_1001    conda-forge
bz2file                   0.98                       py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.3.9             hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               0.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
comtypes                  1.1.7                 py37_1000    conda-forge
conda                     4.6.14                   py37_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.17.8                   py37_1    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1    conda-forge
conda-verify              3.1.1                 py37_1000    conda-forge
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         3    defaults
contextlib2               0.5.5                      py_2    conda-forge
cryptography              2.6.1            py37hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.64.1               h4496350_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.7           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1         py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
dask                      1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
distributed               1.27.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
docutils                  0.14                  py37_1001    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                 py37_1000    conda-forge
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.10                     py_0    conda-forge
flask                     1.0.2                      py_2    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h5db478b_0    conda-forge
future                    0.17.1                py37_1000    conda-forge
gensim                    3.7.1            py37h6538335_1    conda-forge
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0    defaults
gevent                    1.4.0            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.6                        py_0    conda-forge
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.9.0           nompi_py37h3cb27cb_1102    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.4          nompi_hcc15c50_1106    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
html5lib                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1    defaults
icu                       58.1                     vc14_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.8                   py37_1000    conda-forge
imageio                   2.5.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        0.9                      py37_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.3                      203    defaults
ipykernel                 5.1.0           py37h39e3cac_1002    conda-forge
ipython                   7.5.0            py37h39e3cac_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.18                   py37_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
jmespath                  0.9.4                      py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_3    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.35.6                   py37_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
keyring                   19.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.3            hdd46e55_1001    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
libarchive                3.3.3             h0005e80_1004    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                     8_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.64.1               h4496350_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1005    conda-forge
liblief                   0.9.0                ha925a31_2    defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16            h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                h642c060_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h016b793_1002    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h9ce36c8_0    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.32            heafd4d3_1002    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.28.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
locket                    0.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.3.3            py37heafd4d3_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    defaults
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    defaults
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.0.3                    py37_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.0.3            py37h3e3dc42_1    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.16                   py37_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
mkl                       2019.3                      203    defaults
mkl-service               2.0.1            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
mkl_fft                   1.0.12           py37hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.4            py37h830ac7b_0    conda-forge
mock                      3.0.4                    py37_0    conda-forge
more-itertools            4.3.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37he980bc4_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    defaults
multipledispatch          0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.3                        py_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.2.5                      py_0    conda-forge
nose                      1.3.7                 py37_1002    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.8                    py37_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.43.1           py37hf9181ef_0    defaults
numexpr                   2.6.9           py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.3           py37h19fb1c0_0    defaults
numpy-base                1.16.3           py37hc3f5095_0    defaults
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openpyxl                  2.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1b               hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
packaging                 19.0                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.24.2           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.7.2                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
partd                     0.3.9                      py_0    conda-forge
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0    conda-forge
pathlib2                  2.3.3                 py37_1000    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pep8                      1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pillow                    6.0.0            py37h9a613e6_0    conda-forge
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                    py_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    0.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         2    defaults
prometheus_client         0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.6.2            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
py                        1.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37ha925a31_2    defaults
pycodestyle               2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.3           py37hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_1    conda-forge
pycrypto                  2.6.1           py37hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37h636d3bd_0    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.3.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
pyodbc                    4.0.26           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2    defaults
pyreadline                2.1                   py37_1000    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.15.1           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.6.8                 py37_1002    conda-forge
pytables                  3.5.1            py37hb9ab341_1    conda-forge
pytest                    4.4.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
pytest-arraydiff          0.3                        py_0    conda-forge
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-doctestplus        0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.3                hb12ca83_0    conda-forge
python-crfsuite           0.9.6           py37he980bc4_1000    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python-libarchive-c       2.8                   py37_1004    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h452e1ab_1    conda-forge
pywin32                   224             py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.1              py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     18.0.1           py37he7828b0_1    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.7                hc6833c9_1    conda-forge
qtawesome                 0.5.7              pyh8a2030e_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.4.3                      py_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.7.1              pyhde82777_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.21.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.71         py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
s3transfer                0.2.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h6538335_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.20.3           py37h3d241f0_1    conda-forge
scipy                     1.2.1            py37h29ff71c_0    defaults
seaborn                   0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
singledispatch            3.4.0.3               py37_1000    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8          py37h6538335_1000    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py37_1000    conda-forge
smart_open                1.8.3                      py_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7             h6538335_1002    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sortedcollections         1.1.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 1.9.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
sphinx                    2.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1    defaults
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                      py_1    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.4                    py37_0    defaults
spyder-kernels            0.4.4                    py37_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.3.3            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.26.0            hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.9.0           py37hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0    conda-forge
tblib                     1.3.2                      py_1    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
toolz                     0.9.0                      py_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.2            py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.31.1                     py_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
twython                   3.7.0                      py_0    conda-forge
unicodecsv                0.14.1                     py_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4    defaults
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.15.2                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.1                   py37_0    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0    conda-forge
win_unicode_console       0.5                   py37_1000    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py37_1002    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.11.1           py37hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
xlsxwriter                1.1.8                      py_0    conda-forge
xlwings                   0.15.8                   py37_0    conda-forge
xlwt                      1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7             hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.1             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
zict                      0.1.4                      py_0    conda-forge
zipp                      0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1004    conda-forge
zstd                      1.3.3                    vc14_1    conda-forge

(base) C:\>
(base) C:\>CONDA INSTALL pyqt5
```

Does anyone has any idea that might help?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, however, for me, the solution was an easy one. Please go through the following points.

1. Keep a native python installed on your machine.
2. Run "pip install pyqt5-tools" from cmd.
3. You should have a message on screen post-installation - "Successfully installed click-7.0 pyqt5-5.13.0 pyqt5-tools-5.13.0.1.5 python-dotenv-0.10.3" :

[Installation snap for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfFId.png)

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: "pip install pyqt5-tools" saved my day on Linux

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem "qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found" after an update to spyder 4.0.1

After trying `$pip3 install -U pyqt5 --user` I got the error message:

_'ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.14.1 which is incompatible.'_

So I updated with a compatible version:

`pip3 install pyqt5==5.12 --user`

And now spyder is working.

Comment: You saved me a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

The real fix that worked for me, because I really did this, was to install the module that was causing the error. That is the PySide module.

Do not install PySide (`pip install PySide`) unless you are using Python 3.4 or less.
If you are running Python 3.4 and up (up to 3.7), you need to install PySide2 (`pip install PySide2`).

Comment: Please format your code. It's hard to read it.

Comment: @Love, you can always suggest edits if something is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that you are using a different environment from where the PyQt is installed. I was using anaconda environment. Usually `pip install` won't work in conda (at least for me). I used the command
`conda install pyqt` and it worked. Hope this helps